# this is my boundary fill pgm in python bt it fills only half of the boundary

Tags: python, opencv

this is my boundary fill pgm in python bt it fills only half of the boundary

```
def is_equal(a, b):
    _equal = a[0]==b[0] and a[1]==b[1] and a[2]==b[2]
    return _equal

def boundary_fill(src, x, y, fill_color, boundary_color):
    print "x , y ", x, y
    try:
        color_at_xy = src[y, x]
    except IndexError:
        return
    if not is_equal(color_at_xy,fill_color) and not is_equal(color_at_xy,boundary_color):
        src[y, x] = fill_color
        #boundary_fill(src, x + 1, y, fill_color, boundary_color)
        boundary_fill(src, x - 1, y, fill_color, boundary_color)
        boundary_fill(src, x, y + 1, fill_color, boundary_color)
        boundary_fill(src, x, y - 1, fill_color, boundary_color)
```

when the comment is removed---

```
File "as.py", line 5, in is_equal
    _equal = a[0]==b[0] and a[1]==b[1] and a[2]==b[2]
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in cmp
```

---this error occurs
plz hlp me to solve this
thanks in advance

Comment: Please fix your formatting

Comment: Why would I want your code in a comment?

Comment: boundary_fill is being called recursively (boundary_fill calls boundary_fill from inside itself). Is that intentional? I guess, not, so then that's what you need to fix.

Comment: **we used recursion intentionally. To stop it exception is given. But it doesn't stop. why is that??**

Comment: **the pblm is solved thanks to all.**

Answer (score 1):

```
import cv2  
import numpy as np   
import sys  

def is_equal(a, b):  
    _equal = a[0]==b[0] and a[1]==b[1] and a[2]==b[2]   
    return _equal  
sys.setrecursionlimit(10000)
def boundary_fill(src, x, y, fill_color, boundary_color):
    print "x , y ", x, y
    try:
        color_at_xy = src[y, x]
    except IndexError:
        return
    if not is_equal(color_at_xy,fill_color) and not is_equal(color_at_xy,boundary_color):
        src[y, x] = fill_color
        boundary_fill(src, x + 1, y, fill_color, boundary_color)
        boundary_fill(src, x - 1, y, fill_color, boundary_color)
        boundary_fill(src, x, y - 1, fill_color, boundary_color)
        boundary_fill(src, x, y + 1, fill_color, boundary_color)
        boundary_fill(src, x + 1, y - 1, fill_color, boundary_color)
        boundary_fill(src, x + 1, y + 1, fill_color, boundary_color)
        boundary_fill(src, x - 1, y - 1, fill_color, boundary_color)
        boundary_fill(src, x - 1, y + 1, fill_color, boundary_color)
```